# Node Js / Rotas / Controllers

Tags: node.js

Estou começando a estudar o nodejs e surgiu uma dúvida:

Bom eu queria fazer uma api para alimentar o front - end web e mobile com essa api

no caso eu tenho essas rotas (apenas para estudo):

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = express.Router();

const ProductController = require('./controllers/ProductController');
//primeira rota
routes.get("/products", ProductController.index);
routes.get("/products/:id", ProductController.show);
routes.post("/products", ProductController.store);
routes.put("/products/:id", ProductController.update);
routes.delete("/products/:id", ProductController.delete);

module.exports = routes;
```

Bom eu fiquei  com dúvida como eu conseguiria fazer com que determinada rota só fosse acessada pelo meu front-end de mobile ou web

um exemplo: Para cadastrar um produto, como eu conseguiria limitar isso apenas para o meu front-end( ou seja um dashboard de administrador acessar essa rota), e caso um usuario comum consiga achar essa rota não conseguisse adicionar um produto .. ( creio que isso seja relacionado com segurança? )

Se alguém poder me dar dicas de o que estudar para limitar determinada rota apenas para o meu front - end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para a segurança do acesso a sua API, uma das alternativas mais comuns é utilizar token. O token seria um código gerado pela sua aplicação no processo de login. Este código deveria ser devolvido no cabeçalho de todas as requisições (Bearer Token). Antes de executar uma rota, ele seria verificado utilizando um "middleware", que é um trecho de código executado antes de atender a requisição. Se ele existir, ou se ele existir mas o seu conteúdo não for válido, então a rota não é executada.

Através do token, você pode validar se aquele usuário tem permissão para acessar a rota

Aqui tem um exemplo de validação de rotas e token com JWT

Arquivo de rotas:

```js
const express = require("express");
const validate = require("express-validation");
const handle = require("express-async-handler");
const routes = express.Router();
const authMiddleware = require("./app/middlewares/auth");
const UsuarioController = require("./app/controllers/UsuarioController");
const FerramentasController = require("./app/controllers/FerramentasController");

routes.post("/login", validate(validatorLogin), handle(UsuarioController.login));
routes.post(
  "/usuario",
  handle(UsuarioController.cadastrar)
);
routes.get("/ferramentas", handle(FerramentasController.listar));
routes.get("/ferramentas/:id", handle(FerramentasController.detalhe));
//As rotas a partir daqui exigem autenticação
routes.use(authMiddleware);
routes.post(
  "/ferramentas",
  handle(FerramentasController.cadastrar)
);
routes.delete("/ferramentas/:id", handle(FerramentasController.remover));

module.exports = routes;
```

Aqui tem um exemplo de como seria o "authMiddleware" responsável por validar o token antes de executar a rota:

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const authConfig = require("../../config/auth");
const { promisify } = require("util");
module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeader) {
    res.status("401").json({ error: "Token não informado" });
  }
  const [, token] = authHeader.split(" "); // Quebra o header num array e pega o segundo elemento (token sem o Bearer)
  try {
    //Transforma uma funcao que usa callbacks numa promisse
    const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, authConfig.secret);
    req.userID = decoded.id; // Adiciona em todas as requisicoes que utilizaram este middleware o ID do usuário
    return next(); // Middleware tem sempre req, res e next
  } catch (error) {
    res.status("401").json({ error: "Token inválido" });
  }
};
```

Dentro da rota, você vai poder validar o req.userID recuperado pelo middleware, e validar se o usuário tem permissão para utilizar aquela rota.

Em relação a bloquear o acesso por Web ou Mobile, você poderia pensar em criar um header (cabeçalho) personalizado. Então além do token ser válido, o cabeçalho também deveria ter uma determinada informação para que a rota seja executada.

Aqui tem um tutorial de como implementar um JWT token

https://www.luiztools.com.br/post/autenticacao-json-web-token-jwt-em-nodejs/

Comment: Muito obrigado vou ler com bastante atenção e tentar aplicar!